# Windows 10 not reading some MP4 tags

Tags: windows-10, mp3, mp4, tags

Suddenly (I think last windows update cause it) some of my MP4/MP3 files doesn't show tags (Artist, Title and Year) in Windows Explorer but I can see them in Mp3tag program on the same computer and I also see them in Windows 7 computer.

Also in Windows Explorer > View > "Large Icons" - those files have no thumbnail and there is no info on the length of the video or music.

This happened only to some of the files and I don't see deference with other files.

UPDATE:
I used program mediainfo to analyze good and bad files and all bad files had a tag "WM/MediaClassPrimaryID".

Comment: If possible, please provide the output of `ffprobe` ([get here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)) for a working and non-working file.

Comment: Not sure how to use `ffprobe` as it says that "output file does not contain any stream"

Answer (score 1):

I found out that some people have even problem playing files with a tag `WM/MediaClassPrimaryID`.
Out of this problem, one developer created a program to remove this tag available here: [MP4 xtra atom remover](https://auroraborealissoftware.jimdo.com/)

Comment: Can you please include the summary of that application on your answer? Also see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/880618).